# R 3d plot with categorical colors

Tags: r, plot

I have 4 columns of data in R that looks like this

```
x   y   z  group
```

the `group` columns has categorical values, so it is a discrete set of values, whereas the other three columns are continuous.

I want to make a 3d plot in R with `x`, `y`, and `z`, and where the color of the dot is given by "group". I also want to have a legend to this plot. How can I do this? I don't have a particular preference on the actual colors. I suppose `rainbow(length(unique(group))` should do fine.

Comment: Look at the `scatterplot3d` or `rgl` packages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example using `scatterplot3d` and based on the example in the vignette

```
library(scatterplot3d)

# some basic dummy data
DF <- data.frame(x = runif(10),
  y = runif(10), 
  z = runif(10), 
  group = sample(letters[1:3],10, replace = TRUE))

# create the plot, you can be more adventurous with colour if you wish
s3d <- with(DF, scatterplot3d(x, y, z, color = as.numeric(group), pch = 19))

# add the legend using `xyz.convert` to locate it 
# juggle the coordinates to get something that works.
legend(s3d$xyz.convert(0.5, 0.7, 0.5), pch = 19, yjust=0,
       legend = levels(DF$group), col = seq_along(levels(DF$group)))
```

[image]

Or, you could use `lattice` and `cloud`, in which case you can construct the key using `key`

```
cloud(z~x+y, data = DF, pch= 19, col.point = DF$group, 
  key = list(points = list(pch = 19, col = seq_along(levels(DF$group))), 
  text = list(levels(DF$group)), space = 'top', columns = nlevels(DF$group)))
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to make a version that's rotatable such as what plot3d makes?

Comment: use `rgl`. I'll try and add an example

Comment: Awesome, looking forward to it

Comment: CodeGuy, how did you manage to sort out the colours for each of the dots? I have a sequence of values between 0.0 and 1.2 for which I would like to assign colours for use in the 3D plot. So, 0.0-0.19 = Red, 0.2-0.39 = Blue and so forth.... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: using `as.numeric()` on `group` results in NAs and a warning from R that `NAs introduced by coercion`.